# How to use authentication token in Django with Django OAuth Toolkit (not REST)

Tags: python, django, oauth

I'm using the following library http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/ which seems to not be as well documented as I would like, and after I followed its tutorial I am able to have a working system in which I have protected views that need the authorization token, and I can access them using curl and adding the token. Curl is nice to test, but it's not practical, and I failed at developing it.

So I have a very simple protected view:

```
class Test(ProtectedResourceView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Hello, OAuth2!')
```

If I try to access, I will get a 403, and if I ask for the token and put it in the header using curl I can actually get it to work.

In the other hand, I have another view that gets the authorization_token, lifetime, refresh_token, .. in a dictionary (after using JSON from Django).

At this point I'm lost. I don't know what to do with the authorization token so that the user can actually use it and access to the protected view. I tried to manually add the token to the cookies but it didn't work and doesn't seem to be a good idea neither. I guess after I do something, the user can access the protected view.

Thanks.